# Opencv get average color of detected object

Tags: python, image, opencv, colors, mask

I have a mask of an object I've detected. Now I want to calculate the average color of the object. Is there a way to just check the unmasked pixels?

And what would be the best way to get the average color?

Should I use a Cluster or  get the average g,b and r values ?

(I'm using python 3.5 and opencv 3.1 with extras.)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use [cv::mean](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mean) with mask. It will give you Scalar with color components.